# Trying to bring my button to the front, tried zIndex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to bring a button.js component to the front of my background carousel. Tried using zIndex, worked fine with my logo but not with my button?

Button code:

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.buttonContainer} >
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle} >
      <Text style={textStyle} >
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

const styles = {
  buttonContainer: {
    zIndex: 999,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    zIndex: 999,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -200,
    flex: .3,
    alignSelf: 'auto',
    backgroundColor: '#ffff00',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    width: 250,
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  textStyle: {
    zIndex: 999,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#000000',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  }
};

export default Button;
```

Code for my app. Notice how i have literally added zIndex 999 for my button, and it still has not worked.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.carouselContainer}>
      <BackgroundCarousel images={images}>
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image source={logo} style={styles.logo} />
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>Hello World</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button style={{ zIndex: 999 }}>
            Let's Get Started
          </Button>
        </View>
      </BackgroundCarousel>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  carouselContainer: {
    zIndex: 1,
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1
  },
  logoContainer: {
    zIndex: 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: "center",
    top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 450
  },
  logo: {
    zIndex: 2,
    width: 125,
    height: 125,
  },
  logoText: {
    zIndex: 2,
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '500',
    borderColor: 'white',
    fontFamily: "Baskerville-Bold",
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 999,
  }
});
```

Basically, is there another way to bring the button forward? Seeing as how zIndex is not working for me in this case.

Comment: remove <View> from your  <View>
          <Button style={{ zIndex: 999 }}>
            Let's Get Started
          </Button></View>. Because you are already using View in your button.js and try

Answer (score 0):

z-index is only relative to that element's parent so as mentioned by @prakash-karena delete the view that surrounding your button.

```
<View style={styles.carouselContainer}>
  <BackgroundCarousel images={images}>
    <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
      <Image source={logo} style={styles.logo} />
      <Text style={styles.logoText}>Hello World</Text>
    </View>
    <Button style={{ zIndex: 999 }}>
       Let's Get Started
    </Button>
  </BackgroundCarousel>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe zIndex is supported in the latest version of react native for iOS only, order that you place the elements in determines its layout order. you can try making overflow visible of scrollview.